# Find and replace text with capitalized text in Excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, replace, spreadsheet

I've been tasked with reformatting a number of records in a spreadsheet to conform to a unified standard.  We have a column containing a large amount of text, along with HTML tags, but I only need to target the  tags.  Our src paths merely need to be capitalized, but not the *entire path*.  However, the paths all follow this general format.

```
(something)/custom_design/directory/(more directories)/imageName.jpg
```

I only need to capitalize `/custom_design/directory/(more directories)/`.  I'll remove the `(something)` at the beginning of the src path later.  Due to the enormous size of this file and the lack of a unified file structure (some image paths use `img`, others use `images`, etc.), it would be extremely time-consuming to go through each and every cell in that column and manually change the paths.  Is there a faster approach to capitalizing these file paths?  Find and replace only goes so far when you don't know the specific directories.

I should mention that the reason I want to target these specific strings, rather than the entire cell's contents, is because these cells are filled with a lot of other descriptive text that shouldn't be completely capitalized.

Comment: What is `(more directories)`, does that include more forward slashes? Are they really forward slashes (`/`) or backslashes (\\)? I would expect backslashes. You need to give a better example of what a cell's content could actually look like. Once you break out this path, you can use `Split` and get what you want from it.

Comment: The following is an example of one of the records I need to edit: `CUSTOM_DESIGN/pt-tab/IMG/lightweight_portable.png`

CUSTOM_DESIGN and IMG are in all caps because I attempted the find and replace approach already.  All of the image paths are similar to this, but again, there's no telling how many directories are between the first slash and the final one just before the file name.

Comment: So you want everything capitalized between the first item in the path and the last item? Is a cell's content only going to contain `CUSTOM_DESIGN/pt-tab/IMG/lightweight_portable.png`, or is there other text in the cell with it?

Comment: The cell's contents consist of more HTML tags to the point where it's practically code for an individual web page.  I only need to target these image paths because we're uploading the rest of the file unchanged to a database.

Comment: OP, this isn't tagged as `VBA`, but are you open to `VBA` solution?

Comment: Possibly.  I've never used VBA, nor do I know what it is, but if it's simple enough to understand and implement, I can try it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial solution for excel. You can use the logic this equation is using to `Substitute` text by finding their location as determined by back slashes in text (`/`). The equation is combination of `Substitute`, `Left`, `Right`, and `Find`.

When your original string is in `A1`.....

```
B1 = SUBSTITUTE(A1,RIGHT(LEFT(A1,FIND("/",A1,FIND("/",A1)+1)-1),FIND("/",A1)),UPPER(RIGHT(LEFT(A1,FIND("/",A1,FIND("/",A1)+1)-1),FIND("/",A1))))
```

---

I moved the cells over from `A:B` to `G:H` to limit size of photo. You can deconstruct this logic to isolate the strings you want. It's not pretty, but this is the only way I personally know how to do this in Excel.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't appear to work.  It's having the side effect of changing text within the cell outside of the image source.  For instance, `<h3>Description</h3>`, which is the first line of text in this cell, becomes `<h3>DescrIPTION</H3>`, something I don't want.

I know for a fact that the image path will begin with `custom_design/`, if that helps.

Comment: This was not meant to be a copy/paste/done solution. Rather show you how to go about working this out for your problem. You can see the input, output, and method to produce output (which can be applied to your problem with some effort)

Comment: no where in your sample string do I see the values "<" or ">"